# Are sp sizes in Jetpack Compose different from XML sp sizes?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-xml

This might be an odd question, but is `sp` as defined in Jetpack Compose different from `sp` in XML? We have an XML style that we use in `TextView` defined as follows:

```
    <style name="Body">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">-0.03125</item>
    </style>
```

We also have a font family defined in XML and applied to the theme via `android:fontFamily` and `fontFamily`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        app:font="@font/some_font_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="500" />

    <font
        app:font="@font/some_font_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="500" />

    <font
        app:font="@font/some_font_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />

    <font
        app:font="@font/cera_pro_bold_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="700" />

</font-family>
```

Moving to Jetpack Compose, we have a data class that contains `TextStyles` and the definition of the font family where we tried to mimic the definition in the XML:

```kotlin
data class AppTypography(
    private val someFontFamily: FontFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.some_font_regular, FontWeight.W500, FontStyle.Normal),
        Font(R.font.some_font_bold, FontWeight.W700, FontStyle.Normal),
        Font(R.font.some_font_italic, FontWeight.W500, FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.some_font_pro_bold_italic, FontWeight.W700, FontStyle.Italic),
    ),
    // ...
    val body: TextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = someFontFamily,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 12.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp
    ),
    // ...
)
internal val LocalTypography = staticCompositionLocalOf { AppTypography() }
```

This data class is in turn used in this object, which provides access to typography, colors, etc:

```kotlin
object AppTheme {
    val colors: AppColors
        @Composable
        get() = LocalColors.current
    val typography: AppTypography
        @Composable
        get() = LocalTypography.current
    val dimensions: AppDimensions
        @Composable
        get() = LocalDimensions.current
    val shapes: AppShapes
        @Composable
        get() = LocalShapes.current
}
```

Finally, we use this object as an actual Composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    colors: AppColors = lightColors(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val rememberedColors = remember { colors.copy() }.apply { updateColorsFrom(colors) }
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalColors provides rememberedColors,
        LocalTypography provides AppTheme.typography,
        LocalDimensions provides AppTheme.dimensions,
        LocalShapes provides AppTheme.shapes,
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

We then use the `body` style in one of our `Texts`:

```kotlin
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp),
    text = stringResource(stringResourceId),
    style = AppTheme.typography.body,
    color = AppTheme.colors.onSurface
)
```

Comparing the text size in the traditional View system versus in Compose (XML on the left, Compose on the right):

[image]

Both use 12sp as text size, but the Compose one looks smaller. To be fair even the icon looks smaller as well. I'm not sure what could cause this difference, maybe the outer Composable's paddings may have an effect? Anyone faced a similar behaviour when migrating their views to Compose?

Comment: Are they using the same font?  Different fonts are bigger at the same size value.  You can see that by opening up a word processor and typing a few words in different fonts all at the same size.  The XML one looks bolded to me, compared to the compose, as well as bigger

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan, I would answer that they should be using the same font, but looking at how we defined our font family in Compose versus how we usually define it in XML, there might be a difference after all

Comment: Is there any update on this issue ?

Comment: Hi @sgurdag, I filed an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239586892) with Google about this and the advice I got was that fonts in Compose aren't guaranteed to match 100% with XML--you will need to tinker with  settings such as `letterSpacing` and `includeFontPadding` (which is available in Compose 1.2.0) to match with XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the advice I got after filing an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239586892) with Google about this is to tinker with attributes such as `letterSpacing` and `includeFontPadding` (available in Compose 1.2.0 I believe). In my case, using the `Body` style I mentioned, I got close to how fonts look like in XML by:

- setting `letterSpacing` to `(-0.5).sp`
- setting `fontSize` to `16.sp`
- setting `lineHeight` to `24.sp`

I also got confused with how font sizes were defined in our app--we have two `dimens.xml` files, one for `hdpi` and `xxhdpi`, and it turns out I used the smaller `hdpi` font size (`12 sp`) when I translated the font sizes from XML to Compose when I should've used the larger one (`16 sp`). I haven't tried a solution  to having different font sizes depending on density, but this [approach](https://proandroiddev.com/supporting-different-screen-sizes-on-android-with-jetpack-compose-f215c13081bd) looks promising.